# Developing a Java app that runs both on the web and as an Android app?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a game which would work both on the web, as an applet, and on the Android phone, as an app.

Is that possible to do, and if so, what do I need to be aware of to make that work (i.e if there are any settings that I shouldn't hard code and instead determine them based on the user's device when the game is run, or any java libraries that I shouldn't use?).

Also, the game needs to accept touchscreen as input for the Android app. Is that possible to build into the same game which will also be run as an applet? May be so at run time, the applet decides whether to use Mouse or Touchscreen for the input when it is run?

Comment: Your username gives me an overwhelming urge to click the downvote button.

Comment: Thanks for not giving in to such evil urges. Stay strong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although Android apps are written in Java, the framework around the app is extremely different of the framework wrapped around an applet.  You won't be able to have one .jar file that you can include as an applet and throw at an Android device because that's just not how it works.

You will however probably be able to create all the game logic and objects and have them in be shared with the applet code and android app.  You can probably even get away with having them in one repository and project (although it's probably going to have to be an Android project that you then wedge in your app build scripts).

In order to tackle the different controls for your game you are probably going to have to abstract away the input, and have your game/level object have a call back like userHasPoked(int x, int y) and then have the applet call that method on click of the mouse and the android app calls it on touch (which is oddly still called onClick).

I think it'll be a long road, but much easier than rewriting the whole thing.  It'll probably seem like a lot more work up front, but once you are done wedging your code into an applet and an Android app, you'll probably "never" have to touch that code again and can just keep adding to the game.

I wouldn't underestimate the task, but that sounds like a very fun programming exercise.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. So the only new code I'd have to write is the actual event handlers, and the deployment process would be slightly different for Android and Java? Or is there any other part of the code which I'd have to rewrite differently for both web and android?

Comment: @ClickUpvote: "So the only new code I'd have to write is the actual event handlers" -- no, the new code would be "the entire UI". "and the deployment process would be slightly different for Android and Java" -- I would describe it as "substantially different" or "not very much the same". I'm still stunned that anyone in this day and age even *runs* applets, let alone *writes* them.

Comment: @CommonsWare Then what would you suggest is a better way to have a java game run in both a browser and Android?

Comment: @ClickUpvote: I question the entire merit of "have a java game run in... a browser". Games played in Web browsers are typically implemented in Flash or HTML/JavaScript, from what I can see. The only thing deader in-browser than applets are ActiveX Controls (well, that and the `<blink>` tag).

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't see any reason not to have my game run in a web browser as well, why should i limit myself to android. My question was, are there any better ways of running java in browser than applets, e.g Java fx or any newer techs?

Comment: I haven't spent enough time looking into JavaFX, I think that supposed to be the future of Java UI.  So I don't think it replaces applets so much as swing.  Also I think that if you have a very well controlled interface that allows access to all the things your game will need to do (all the controls and contact points for any game-logic), then you won't have to repeat any code "underneath" that interface.  Just the applet implementation of it and the Android implementation of it.  I'm not saying those two implementations are small, but I am saying you'll likely only have to write that once.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of game do you develop? It may be the better approach to develop an Javascript game.

That can be installed with [phonegap](http://phonegap.com) (cordova) onto an android device.

Answer (score 1):

Let me break this for you....

`Model` - The Business Logic and Data

`View` - The Display of the Output of the Model

`Controller` - On which the action is done.

The advantage of using this `MVC` architecture is that, you can keep the **same model** and **keep changing the Views**.

So keeping this idea in mind, you can have the same model for both the Web App and the Android App, and then implement each others Views to it respectively.